# geom_map "map_id" reference issue

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth map of US counties with two datasets connected by FIPS codes. I am using the `maps` package `county` and `county.fips` data, combined into one data.table like this (probably not the most elegant way of integrating the FIPS data):

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(maps)
    library(data.table)
    county <- map_data("county")    
    data(county.fips)
    county.fips <- as.data.table(county.fips)
    county.fips$polyname <- as.character(county.fips$polyname)    
    county.fips[, paste0("type", 1:2) := tstrsplit(polyname, ",")]
    names(county.fips) <- c("FIPS","polyname","region","subregion")
    county <- merge(county, county.fips, by=c("region", "subregion"), all=T)
    county <- county[,1:7]
    county <- as.data.table(county)
    county <- na.omit(county)
    setkey(county, order)
    county[region=="washington" & subregion=="san juan", FIPS := 53055]
    county[region=="washington" & subregion=="pierce", FIPS := 53053]
    county[region=="florida" & subregion=="okaloosa", FIPS := 12091]
    county[region=="louisiana" & subregion=="st martin", FIPS := 22099]
    county[region=="north carolina" & subregion=="currituck", FIPS := 37053]
    county[region=="texas" & subregion=="galveston", FIPS := 48167]
    county[region=="virginia" & subregion=="accomack", FIPS := 51001]
```

I want to use the `county` dataset here to make the map and use a different dataset with a corresponding FIPS column to fill out the respective counties. The issue comes up when using `geom_map` and specifically the `map_id` argument.

The following code returns the error `Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0` when I run it with `map_id=FIPS`

```
    ggplot() +
  geom_map(data=county, map=county,
           aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=FIPS))
```

However, running it with `map_id=region` returns a normal map *and* running it with `map_id=subregion` returns a map with about 2 out of 3 states missing. The closest answer I found was [this](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/504), suggesting that `map_id` needs to be set to `region` or `id`, but changing the `FIPS` column name didn't help.

Can anyone explain what is going on here? My understanding is that `map_id` is only needed as a key to another `df$column`; am I incorrect in that? Ideally I would like to be able to tie in my second dataset, through the `FIPS` column, like this:

```
    ggplot() +
  geom_map(data=county, map=county,
           aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=FIPS)) +
  geom_map(data=DT2, map=county,
           aes(fill=Revenue, map_id=FIPS))
```

Comment: Maybe [this blog post](https://www.datascienceriot.com/mapping-us-counties-in-r-with-fips/kris/) could be useful

Answer (score 2):

A couple things going on here. First, I noticed in the example above, it's cutting off the leading zeros on some of the FIPS codes. All FIPS need to be five digits. You can add the leading zeros by adding this line to the end of the data prep.

```
county$FIPS <- formatC(county$FIPS, width = 5, format = "d", flag = "0")
```

As for ggplot, you're missing `group=group` in your aes(). It's hard to reproduce because I'm not sure what you're using for the choropleth fill, but the following should work:

```
ggplot(county, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
geom_polygon(aes(fill = YOUR_FILL_DATA), colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2)
```

EDIT: I generated a column of random numbers to use as a fill rate:

```
county$new.row <- sample(100, size = nrow(county), replace = TRUE)
```

and ran the same ggplot code from above.

[image]

Comment: `geom_map` doesn't need the `group=group` argument (see the documentation). I am using `geom_map` with the shared key column rather than `geom_polygon` because I don't want to merge my `county` dataset with my data dataset (as you have done above), as that would make it unreasonably large (~80k rows for `county` times ~8k rows for my other dataset).