# How does geom_map "map_id" function work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make sense of the use of `geom_map` in ggplot2.

Setup:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
county2 <- map_data("county")
```

Why does this code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_map(data=county2, map=county2, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region), col="white", fill="grey")
```

Produce this correct plot:
[image]

But changing the `map_id=region` to `map_id=subregion` do this?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_map(data=county2, map=county2, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=subregion), col="white", fill="grey")
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`geom_map()` does the work of remembering the polygons in the data frame for you.

Alex *is* correct that `map` has to look like a fortified spatial object. That does the "remembering". `map_id` can be any column that hold the identifier for other layers.

Your first call to `geom_map()` should (usually) be the "base layer", similar to what you'd do with a full-on GIS program, that has the polygon outlines and perhaps a base fill.

Other calls to `geom_map()` can add other aesthetics (including other shapefiles).

Here are some examples to demonstrate.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(mapdata)
library(ggthemes)
library(tibble)
library(viridis)

us <- map_data("state")

choro_dat <- data_frame(some_other_name=unique(us$region),
                        some_critical_value=sample(10000, length(some_other_name)))

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=us, map=us,
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=region),
                    color="#2b2b2b", fill=NA, size=0.15)
gg <- gg + coord_map("polyconic")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(plot.margin=margin(20,20,20,20))
gg
```

[image]

```
county <- map_data("county")

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=county, map=county,
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=region),
                    color="#2b2b2b", fill=NA, size=0.15)
gg <- gg + coord_map("polyconic")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(plot.margin=margin(20,20,20,20))
gg
```

[image]

The reason for the strange county mappings is that the county names aren't unique.

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=county, map=county,
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=subregion),
                    color="#2b2b2b", fill=NA, size=0.15)
gg <- gg + coord_map("polyconic")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(plot.margin=margin(20,20,20,20))
gg
```

[image]

Note here how the `map_id` is not `region` or `id` but it still works. That' b/c the values in that column are in `us$region`.

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=us, map=us,
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=region),
                    color="#2b2b2b", fill=NA, size=0.15)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=choro_dat, map=us,
                    aes(fill=some_critical_value,
                        map_id=some_other_name),
                    color="white", size=0.15)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_viridis(name="Value")
gg <- gg + coord_map("polyconic")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(plot.margin=margin(20,20,20,20))
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position=c(0.85, 0.2))
gg
```

[image]

Notice here that we can use a different spatial objects and wrap an outline around our map:

```
outline <- map_data("usa")

gg <- gg + geom_map(data=outline, map=outline,
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=region),
                    color="black", fill=NA, size=1)
gg
```

[image]

One final one: a composite using three spatial objects layered on top of each other. Note that you prbly want to use something like [this](http://github.com/hrbrmstr/albersusa) if you really want to map counties since it has FIPS codes (i.e. a unique id for each county you can map aesthetics to).

```
state <- map_data("state")
county <- map_data("county")
usa <- map_data("usa")

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=county, map=county,
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=region),
                    color="#2b2b2b", fill=NA, size=0.15)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=state, map=state,
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=region),
                    color="#2166ac", fill=NA, size=0.5)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=usa, map=usa,
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=region),
                    color="#4d9221", fill=NA, size=1)
gg <- gg + coord_map("polyconic")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(plot.margin=margin(20,20,20,20))
gg
```

[image]

Comment: So in the map w/ the missing counties, the states that aren't shown contain a county whose name matches a county in another state? Why does this then exclude the entire state and not just the matching counties?

Comment: b/c said state must have counties that ended up in other states. you should do a separate analysis (i.e. non-spatial) on the `region` and `subregion` columns using something like `dplyr` to see how the data overlaps on your own.

Comment: But, for county-level work, you're far better off not using `map_data()` and using a FIPS-oriented shapefile.

Comment: I have actually tried that and ran into an issue described in my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819187/geom-map-map-id-reference-issue?noredirect=1#comment63198615_37819187) - could you have a look there and help me understand why my FIPS column wasn't working with `map_id=`? Thanks for your help on this question, it has made the use of `geom_map` a lot more clear to me.